# Restrict access to all asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, restrict

I am mainlining one asp.net Project, this project is configured in IIS. The website is open for everyone,  when i review the code in asp.net page, its checking window login "enterprise id" and allowing all users to view the all the aspx pages.

Now, my management team requested us to restrict those who are under junior level employees.(Junior engg, Developer, software engg).

I have written the query, passing enterprise id and validate grade, if its junior level , returning "0" values,else returning "1" values.

My questions is,  I do not want go and edit each page and check this query and restrict each page.

can you please suggest , how can i implement simplest and best way to restric the users.

Thanks, 
 --------------------------------------- Update on 09/24/2015

```html
Index.aspx 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string UserStatus = UtilFunctions.ValidateUser();
        Response.Write(UserStatus);
        if (UserStatus == "0")
        {
            Response.Write("<div><font color=red><h1>You are not authorized to view this page</h1></font></div>");
            Response.End();
        }
     }


Utilifunctions.cs 
    public static String ValidateUser()
    {
       
        string CurrentUser = getLoggedOnUser();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                
                myConnection.Open();//Opens the Connection
                myCommand.CommandText = "Select Permission From Temp_Validate Where EnterpriseId='" + CurrentUser + "'";
                SqlDataReader IDReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); //Gets the ID
                IDReader.Read();
                string UserStatus = IDReader["Permission"].ToString();
                IDReader.Close();
                return UserStatus;
            }
        }
```

I implemented the above functionalite in my index.aspx page, if the userstatus equal to "0" , it will display the "You are not authrized to view this message"  and it will end.

I have around 30 aspx page,its currently running in Production. I do not want go include the same code (index.aspx)  in every page load to stop the user validation.

could you please suggest how can i implement without editing all pages.

Updated on 09/28 :   Utilifunction.cs

```html
public static String getLoggedOnUser()
    {    
        String user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        if (user == "") user = "anonymous";

        string UserStatus = IsValidUser(user);

        if (UserStatus == "0")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("PSF_Error.aspx", true);
        }
        return user;            
    }

    public static String IsValidUser(string currentUser)
    {
      
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                //Gets email of the creator of current user
                myConnection.Open();//Opens the Connection
                myCommand.CommandText = "Select Permission From Temp_Validate Where EnterpriseId='" + currentUser + "'";
                SqlDataReader IDReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); //Gets the ID
                IDReader.Read();
                string UserStatus = IDReader["Permission"].ToString();
                IDReader.Close();
                return UserStatus;
            }
        }


    }
```

Index.aspx

```html
Page_load
{
string CurrentUser = UtilFunctions.getLoggedOnUser();

}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the grade validation values? i.e., how does the application know whether a user is junior level?

Generally, page access should be set using roles, and the web.config file. You can see a very simple answer to a similar question, here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1434380.aspx?Restricting+Access+to+Pages+by+Roles

Basically, you set access, based on page-by-page, or directory--by-directory rules. I'm not sure whether that works for your project, though.

Comment: I have two tables "employee" - Employee ID, name, title,   second table : Titles Title Id, Name , level.    example : if i join both tables,   employee name : Mark, 12(titleID), Contractor (Title), S4 ( Level),  i do not want allow s4 level users in all the pages.

Comment: u probably want to implement your custom role provider.  once u have it setup and configure (in web.config), you can do it in code behind.

Comment: I see. @achan is right, if you want to handle this all in your business-side logic. An easier alternative would be to offer login credentials (username and password) to employees, based on their level, but that is not an appropriate solution for larger businesses, nor is it terribly secure. I'll try to find you a good tutorial for setting up roles.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, here:

1) Set up role-based access with Owin or AspNet.Identity. This is probably your best option, but I couldn't find a good tutorial for you. Those packages are well-documented, however, and I'm sure you can figure them out with some effort.

2) Build a Roles table, and customize access yourself. The best example I found was here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875547/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NET

3) Redirect unauthorized users without the use of roles. So something like:

```
public ActionResult SecurePage(User u)
{
    if(u.level == "junior"){
        return RedirectToAction("CustomErrorPage");
    } else {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that that option is terribly secure, but it should work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks,  i researched but not able to implement the above 2 suggestion. I have edited my code, can you please provide suggestion for implementing this functionality without editing each and everypage.  thanks,

Answer (score 0):

after setting up roles you can use a web.config file in every directory specifying [authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8d82143t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and/or use the 'location' element in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

First off, sorry about the confusing code. I've been using MVC, and you've clearly posted your code behind.

I don't think that you can achieve what you are trying to do, without adding your code to each page, or learning about roles. You could reduce some code duplication in a number of clever ways, but I can't think of anything that doesn't seem like a total hack.

If you want to, say, put all of your secure pages in the same directory, and restrict low-level access to that directory, you are going to have to filter by specific users or, if you can implement them, roles. As I understand it, the deny and allow nodes in your web.config file are setting server side (so IIS, probably) authorization rules, so the keywords and rules you can use are limited. Check this page out, for some basics:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

While it is likely POSSIBLE to build a rule based on values in your DB, doing so would probably be far more work than it would be worth.

Sorry that I can't offer a more satisfactory answer, but I would recommend: 1) Get to work, and add a check to the code behind for each page, or 2) (and I highly suggest this option) close this question, and post another, about implementing roles in .net, and assigning roles to users, in code. If, say, you can use your login page to assign every junior-level user the custom role of Junior, and place all of your secure pages in a directory named SecurePages you could add the following code to your web.config, and achieve exactly what you are trying to do:

```
<location path="SecurePages">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny roles="Junior">
        <deny users="*">
</authorization></system.web></location>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it does not work for my project.  lot of complicated code inside the page, each page is acting like seperately.

Comment: The code one i posted in main page.   Is there any trouble when i redirect the page from cs file . ?    if the user is not validate, i plan to redirect the error page from cs file.  HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("PSF_Error.aspx", true);

Comment: when the index page load, if the user valid, it will function, otherwise, cs file redirect to error page.  could you suggest me, the way i implement is corrrect or not ?  thanks,

Comment: It depends on how secure you want to be. Roles are better, as is implementing the redirect on every page. A restricted user could just type "http://yourdomain.com/Products", or whatever, into a browser in order to circumvent the Index page. Also, somebody who knows a bit more about app architecture might be able to I'm not entirely certain that the page you redirect from will not be cached, which may not matter  in your case.

In short: that was the worst of the three options I suggested below, but it should keep restricted users from surfing your site normally.